# Exporting my Node.JS website for deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to export a version of my project without all the unnecessary node modules that come in the `node_modules` folder.

For the first time I am developing a website using node.js. I used it to include Bootstrap and jQuery, as well as compiling my sass stylesheet.

Now I want to upload it to the server through FTP, but the host does not support Node.Js. Therefore I want to 'compile' a version that does not require Node.js.

Currently when I try to upload the whole project, I am uploading a couple of thousand, but it's just a small website.

This is my package.json:-

```
{
  "name": "veerman",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Veerman Assurantien pkg",
  "main": "init.js",
  "watches": {
    "sass": "styles/**"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass styles/ -o dist/css/ --output-style compressed",
    "dev": "rerun-script"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "Veerman Assurantien"
  },
  "author": "Demiën Drost",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.6.1",
    "rerun-script": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

So, I want to 'build' the project to be able to run on it's own without all the other junk.

Comment: So publish just those files. What's the problem?

Comment: One of the lines in your json above references `dist/` - perhaps that's the directory you're looking for.

Comment: What does your init.js look like? Please paste the code.

Comment: @SLaks I don't want to publish the website to NPM. 
@JamesThorpe The only content of `dist/` is the compiled sass file.
@maxpaj init.js doesn't hold any contents.

Comment: I believe you are confused. There is no compile in nodejs, also what do mean junk?. If your host doesnt support nodejs then you just cant run a node project on your host and thats the end.

Comment: @Stamos So there is no way to get a version that doesn't require node.js but includes, lets say: bootstrap and jQuery

Comment: If your host doesnt support node thet you will have to use some other language like `php` or change host

Comment: check [Can node.js run in any hosting provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554289/can-node-js-run-in-any-hosting-provider)

Comment: I found that out yes. I myself used node so it became easier to install packages etc. But if I want to use a regular host, I shouldn't. I learned it the hard way, unfortunately. I will just use download bootstrap and jquery then and implement that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your `init.js` is written you should be able to do this.  I'd test it via running your build command/step, then using something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to verify you don't need any of the nodejs stuff.  Just `CD` to the `dist/` folder, run `http-server .` and then goto the url listed in the console.
If that's all great, upload the contents of `dist/`

Comment: My `init.js` file is completely empty. And on executing the command `npm build` it only prints a blank line. Therefor the only contents of my dist/ folder is my compile sass file, which I put there through the `dev` script.

Comment: @DemiënDrost so, you're just making html files and css files in your `dist/` folder?

Comment: @Jace only the CSS files, all the other files are just in the root folder.

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a step to build/move your `/` contents to a `/dist` folder.  Most the time's folks use gulp for this kind of thing.

https://github.com/MrDragonXM15/Gulp-Skeleton seems to have a good skeleton.  I'll try to recreate what you have, but I'm just guessing.